# Why is AuFS not mounting all drives?

Tags: mount

I'm running AuFS on Ubuntu 14.04 with 13 hard drives

Some of my drives can be seen in AuFS and others can not.

Here's an example

Not showing up in AuFS

```
ls -lart /mnt/4tb01/IAm*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3 Apr 12 08:23 /mnt/4tb01/IAmOn4tb01.txt
```

Showing up in AuFS

```
ls -lart /mnt/4tb02/IAm*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 12 08:31 /mnt/4tb02/IAmOn4tb02.txt
```

and the AuFS

```
ls /mnt/4tb02/
IAmOn4tb02.txt  media  snapraid.content
```

Here's my fstab

```
none /mnt/allmediadrives aufs br:/mnt/tvshowsandmusic=rw:/mnt/hdmovies=rw:/mnt/sdmoviesnew=rw:/mnt/3tb01=rw:/mnt/3tb02=rw:/mnt/4tb01=rw:/mnt/4tb02=rw:/mnt/4tb03=rw:/mnt/4tb04=rw:/mnt/4tb05=rw:/mnt/4tb06=rw:/mnt/4tb07=rw:/mnt/4tb08=rw:/mnt/4tb09=rw:,create=mfsrr:42949672960,udba=reval       0       0
```

I also tried mounting from command line.

```
mount -t aufs -o br=/mnt/tvshowsandmusic=rw:/mnt/hdmovies=rw:/mnt/sdmoviesnew=rw:/mnt/3tb01=rw:/mnt/3tb02=rw:/mnt/4tb01=rw:/mnt/4tb02=rw:/mnt/4tb03=rw:/mnt/4tb04=rw:/mnt/4tb05=rw:/mnt/4tb06=rw:/mnt/4tb07=rw:/mnt/4tb08=rw:/mnt/4tb09=rw -o udba=reval none /mnt/allmediadrives
```